# Run daemon server or shell command?

Tags: python, linux, go

I need to validate phone numbers and there is a very good python library that will do this. My stack however is Go and I'm really not looking forward to porting a very large library. Do you think it would be better to use the python library by running a shell command from within the Go codebase or by running a daemon that I then have to communicate with somehow?

Comment: How much communication do you need between the library and the codebase? The more you do, the more setting up a daemon makes sense.

Comment: Curious to see if you get voted to close on this because it's opinion based, or whether one solution is better than another and the question is actually answerable...

Comment: So you'd be using this Python library to validate user input every now an then? As opposed to using it on thousands of records in an existing data set for example? Then performance is hardly a concern, and I would go with the solution that's easier to understand, debug and maintain. Which most likely is spawning a subprocess.

Comment: @peakxu very little. "here's a phone number, is it valid?"

Comment: @LukasGraf that was exactly my thought. There might be times when it gets heavy use (importing lots of numbers) but most of the time it won't be used very frequently.

Comment: @tbeauvais in case you're talking about the Python port of Google's libphonenumber: There seems to be an (experimental) Go port as well: https://github.com/teltechsystems/gophonenumbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python, being an interpreted language, requires the system to load the interpreter each time a script is run from the command line. Also

On my particular system, after disk caching, it takes the system 20ms to execute a script with `import string` (which is plausible for your use case). If you're processing a lot information, and can't submit it all at once, you should consider setting up a daemon to avoid this kind of overhead.

On the other hand, a daemon is more complex to write and test, so you should probably see if a script suits your needs before optimizing prematurely.

There's no answer to your question that fits every possible case. Ultimately, you always have to try the performance with your data and in your system,